# Report on a set of pages in Google Analytics by uploading a URL list

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, reporting, page-views

I have a site where I am trying to gather analytics on the category of a URL. For example, we have stories for both dogs and cats but the URLs for both stories are under "/animals/"

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the number of page views for each category. I was thinking I would go about doing this by pulling out the filtered URLs of each category and applying meta data in a data import to Google Analytics. I was able to import the data, but am unable to filter the data based on the import. I have no way of knowing if the import matched any items, if it was successful or failed.

Curious if anyone else has attempted a similar and what your process has been.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of URLs? Could we built some regexp to identify which is about dogs and which about cats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have only pageviews per each category. Do it in spreadsheet.

1) download a report with pageviews for /animals/ category

2) import data to spreadsheet

3) import URLs for cats and dogs in separate columns in the same spreadsheet

4) using a VLOOKUP function identify is "dog URL" is contained in all pages columns (/animal/ category column), if it is attribute a nomber of pageviews to that URL

5) copy formula for all URLs

About VLOOKUP, INDEX MATCH and oher: http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/